# Using parameters in React event-handlers to manipulate particular state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My state looks like this:

```
state={a:0,b:0,c:0}
```

I am trying to write an eventHandler function that would accept parameter 'value' so I could pass the same function as a prop to several buttons that will setState based on the provided parameter.

```
eventHandler =(value)=>{
this.setState({value:this.state.value+1})
}

<button onClick={this.eventHandler.bind(this,'a')}><button/>
<button onClick={this.eventHandler.bind(this,'b')}><button/>
<button onClick={this.eventHandler.bind(this,'c')}><button/>
```

The idea is that each button accepts the same function with different parameter but changes only state passed in parameter leaving other ones untouched.

I would be also highly interested how it could be implemented if passing this function as a prop to children components and assigning and using the parameter there.

```
<Parent click = {this.eventHandler.bind(this,'')}/>
```

|

```
<button onClick={click('b')}>
```

It is not working and I am not sure that its the correct way of doing this.
I appreciate any help and advices.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what error(s) you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I think this is what you want. The console logs are just so you can see the change to state.

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ly0209wkmq).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    variables: {
      a: 0,
      b: 1
    }
  };

  handleClick = val => {
    const prevVal = this.state.variables[val];

    this.setState(
      { variables: { ...this.state.variables, [val]: prevVal + 1 } },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick("a")}>click a</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick("b")}>click b</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Works amazingly if I pass the function directly to the button, thanks. I would much appreciate if you could also advice me how to make this work for nested objects if my state was state ={variables:{a:0,b:0},} because I can't make it work. And is there a possibility to pass the function to the child, and set the val argument there? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DimitryIvashchuk I've updated the code for a nested object. If you want to pass the function, just pass it as a prop (`this.handleClick`) and set the val parameter in the child component.